# Retrofit não retorna o cep e endereço

Tags: android, post, retrofit, volley

ApiService

```
public interface ApiService {
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("app/endereco/index.php")
Call<dados> validateUser(
        @Field("endereco") String endereco,
        @Field("tipoCEP") String tipoCEP
);
```

}

```
public class dados {

@SerializedName("uf")
@Expose
private String uf;
@SerializedName("localidade")
@Expose
private String localidade;
@SerializedName("locNoSem")
@Expose
private String locNoSem;
@SerializedName("locNu")
@Expose
private String locNu;
@SerializedName("localidadeSubordinada")
@Expose
private String localidadeSubordinada;
@SerializedName("logradouroDNEC")
@Expose
private String logradouroDNEC;
@SerializedName("logradouroTextoAdicional")
@Expose
private String logradouroTextoAdicional;
@SerializedName("logradouroTexto")
@Expose
private String logradouroTexto;
@SerializedName("bairro")
@Expose
private String bairro;
@SerializedName("baiNu")
@Expose
private String baiNu;
@SerializedName("nomeUnidade")
@Expose
private String nomeUnidade;
@SerializedName("cep")
@Expose
private String cep;
@SerializedName("tipoCep")
@Expose
private String tipoCep;
@SerializedName("numeroLocalidade")
@Expose
private String numeroLocalidade;
@SerializedName("situacao")
@Expose
private String situacao;
@SerializedName("faixasCaixaPostal")
@Expose
private List<Object> faixasCaixaPostal = null;
@SerializedName("faixasCep")
@Expose
private List<Object> faixasCep = null;

public String getUf() {
    return uf;
}

public void setUf(String uf) {
    this.uf = uf;
}

public String getLocalidade() {
    return localidade;
}

public void setLocalidade(String localidade) {
    this.localidade = localidade;
}

public String getLocNoSem() {
    return locNoSem;
}

public void setLocNoSem(String locNoSem) {
    this.locNoSem = locNoSem;
}

public String getLocNu() {
    return locNu;
}

public void setLocNu(String locNu) {
    this.locNu = locNu;
}

public String getLocalidadeSubordinada() {
    return localidadeSubordinada;
}

public void setLocalidadeSubordinada(String localidadeSubordinada) {
    this.localidadeSubordinada = localidadeSubordinada;
}

public String getLogradouroDNEC() {
    return logradouroDNEC;
}

public void setLogradouroDNEC(String logradouroDNEC) {
    this.logradouroDNEC = logradouroDNEC;
}

public String getLogradouroTextoAdicional() {
    return logradouroTextoAdicional;
}

public void setLogradouroTextoAdicional(String logradouroTextoAdicional) {
    this.logradouroTextoAdicional = logradouroTextoAdicional;
}

public String getLogradouroTexto() {
    return logradouroTexto;
}

public void setLogradouroTexto(String logradouroTexto) {
    this.logradouroTexto = logradouroTexto;
}

public String getBairro() {
    return bairro;
}

public void setBairro(String bairro) {
    this.bairro = bairro;
}

public String getBaiNu() {
    return baiNu;
}

public void setBaiNu(String baiNu) {
    this.baiNu = baiNu;
}

public String getNomeUnidade() {
    return nomeUnidade;
}

public void setNomeUnidade(String nomeUnidade) {
    this.nomeUnidade = nomeUnidade;
}

public String getCep() {
    return cep;
}

public void setCep(String cep) {
    this.cep = cep;
}

public String getTipoCep() {
    return tipoCep;
}

public void setTipoCep(String tipoCep) {
    this.tipoCep = tipoCep;
}

public String getNumeroLocalidade() {
    return numeroLocalidade;
}

public void setNumeroLocalidade(String numeroLocalidade) {
    this.numeroLocalidade = numeroLocalidade;
}

public String getSituacao() {
    return situacao;
}

public void setSituacao(String situacao) {
    this.situacao = situacao;
}

public List<Object> getFaixasCaixaPostal() {
    return faixasCaixaPostal;
}

public void setFaixasCaixaPostal(List<Object> faixasCaixaPostal) {
    this.faixasCaixaPostal = faixasCaixaPostal;
}

public List<Object> getFaixasCep() {
    return faixasCep;
}

public void setFaixasCep(List<Object> faixasCep) {
    this.faixasCep = faixasCep;
}
```

}

Main no botão

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_login:

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://buscacepinter.correios.com.br/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()))
                    .build();

            ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

            Call<dados> call = apiService.validateUser("Praça Caramuru", "LOG");
            call.enqueue(new Callback<dados>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<dados> call, Response<dados> response) {
                    //Verifica se houve a conexão com sucesso ao webservice
                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                        txt.setText("ERROR onResponde: " + response.code());
                    } else {
                        //requisição retona os dados com sucesso
                        String email = response.body().getLocalidade();
                        String senha = response.body().getCep();
                        txt.append("email: " + email + " - senha: " + senha + "\n");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<dados> call, Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                    txt.setText(t.getMessage());
                }

            });
```

Resposta WebService

```
{
"erro": false,
"mensagem": "DADOS ENCONTRADOS COM SUCESSO.",
"total": 1,
"dados": [
    {
        "uf": "MG",
        "localidade": "Patos de Minas",
        "locNoSem": "",
        "locNu": "",
        "localidadeSubordinada": "",
        "logradouroDNEC": "Pra\u00e7a Apar\u00edcio do S\u00e9rgio",
        "logradouroTextoAdicional": "",
        "logradouroTexto": "",
        "bairro": "Caramuru",
        "baiNu": "",
        "nomeUnidade": "",
        "cep": "38701375",
        "tipoCep": "2",
        "numeroLocalidade": "",
        "situacao": "",
        "faixasCaixaPostal": [],
        "faixasCep": []
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1):

Analisando o seu código acredito que o problema se encontre no tipo de dado esperado.
Nesse cara aqui você está esperando um tipo dado

```
Call<dados> validateUser(
    @Field("endereco") String endereco,
    @Field("tipoCEP") String tipoCEP
);
```

Entretanto o serviço está lhe respondendo com um objeto anterior e esse possuí um array da sua classe dados.

```
{ 
  "erro": false,
  "mensagem": "DADOS ENCONTRADOS COM SUCESSO.",
  "total": 1,
  "dados": []
}
```

Será necessário mapear esse objeto anterior para pegar na resposta do service. Você pode por exemplo criar uma Classe Response que tenha uma string erro, uma string mensagem, um int total e um array da sua classe dados.

Comment: Baseado no tutorial (https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-detect-network-and-conversion-errors-in-onfailure) coloquei Onfailure: if (t instanceof IOException) {Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , "Falha na rede" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // logging probably not necessary
                } else {
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , "Problemas na conversão :(" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   mas, sempre cai em Problemas na conversão. Inspeciona Chrome temos no headers: RequestURL:https://buscacepinter.correios.com.br/app/endereco/carrega-cep-endereco.php

Comment: Obrigado por responder. Fiz uma classe com ajuda do puglins JasonFormatPlus do android studio, com todas as respostas do service, mas não deu certo. Usei 
@JsonIgnoreProperties, para erro, mensagem e total, também sem sucesso. Olhando o inspecionar no Chrome, aparece outro endereço.: buscacepinter.correios.com.br/app/endereco/carrega-cep-endereco.php

Comment: Debugando no inspecionar, me deparei com a seguinte linha de código:   let xhr = ajax('POST', 'carrega-cep-endereco.php', campos, function(json)

Comment: Dentro do teu if-else, se no else tu colocar um Log para o response e colocar um breakpoint, tu consegue ver todas as informações retornadas? Se sim, poderia tirar um print e postar aqui?

Comment: Retorna o clássico "Esperava um objeto, mas o retorno é uma string linha 1 coluna 1 Path $"

Comment: Obrigado a todos. Consegui usando o site:      
   www.journaldev.com/13639/retrofit-android-example-tutorial                                O Problema estava no Pojo mesmo.